# golang: Audio to FLAC conversion without running a executable

Tags: google-app-engine, go, audio, ffmpeg, audio-converter

I am trying to make a Google App Engine that takes a file from Storage, and the converts arbitrary audio file to FLAC. App Engine, however, does not permit running executables.

My current code looks something like this:

```
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, `./ffmpeg`,
    `-i`, `pipe:0`, `pipe:1`, `-ac`, `1`, `-c:a`, `flac`, `-f`, `flac`)
cmd.Stdin = rc
cmd.Stdout = wc

var errOutput bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stderr = &errOutput

err = cmd.Run()
fmt.Printf("Running ffmpeg: %v... \nstderr: %s\n", err, errOutput.String())
```

Tried looking for go packages (e.g. https://github.com/xfrr/goffmpeg) that do this, but all that I found seem to use the same "run executable on inputs" paradigm as the code above.

How should I approach this? Is there a package that provides bindings to FFMPEG or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg functionality in App Engine importing [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python): Python bindings for FFmpeg or for example [Libav](https://libav.org/about/).

Please note that there are [two steps to use third-party library with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27):

1. Add library to requirements file, that will be used during app build: `ffmpeg-python==0.1.17`
2. Add it to the app code: `import ffmpeg`

Examples of video encoding apps for App Engine:

1. [Scalable Video Transcoding With App Engine Flexible](https://medium.com/google-cloud/scalable-video-transcoding-with-app-engine-flexible-621f6e7fdf56).
2. [Distributed FFMPEG using Google App Engine](https://www.feeditout.com/distributed-ffmpeg-gce/).